# javascript of HTML content within a Google Map info window is not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've got the following JSON file:

```
{
   "places" : [
    {
        "place": "A",
        "place_id": "ChIJIQs8RmOQdkcRkR07PeyDqhw",
        "lat": 47.803488,
        "lng": 13.045824
    },
    {
        "place": "B",
        "place_id": "ChIJY60NGmOQdkcRnHyLQNKMWOg",
        "lat": 47.802524,
        "lng": 13.046177
    },
    {
        "place": "​C",
        "place_id": "ChIJKR11Md-QdkcRIcl4Mu8D0DA",
        "lat": 47.773108,
        "lng": 13.069841
    }
  ]
}
```

Based on this data, I'm creating 3 markers.

```
function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.5,13.2)
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var json = "http://127.0.0.1/json/data.json";
$.getJSON(json, function(json1) {
    $.each(json1.places, function (key, data) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            title: data.place
        });

        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, data.place_id);

    });
});
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, myPlace) {
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'infowindowcontent.html?place_id=' + myPlace,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
                infowindow.setContent(data);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    }); 
});
}
```

The called infowindowcontent.html code looks like this:

```
<div>
    <div id="dynamiccontent">no no no</div>
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("dynamiccontent").innerHTML = "hey hey hey"
</script>
```

Each code is working fine on its own.
But the infowindowcontent.html code is called by clicking a marker. The info windows is displayed, but the javascript isn't executed. I still read 'no no no' instead of 'hey hey hey'. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of adding this script in infowindowcontent.html , you should instead add it in the success block of google.maps.event.addEventListener(marker, 'click'......) after calls to `infoWindow.setContent(data); infoWindow.open(map,marker); document.getElementById("dynamiccontent").innerHTML = "hey hey hey";`

Comment: Thank you for pointing me the right direction! Problem solved.